# How to call the js function with onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do set a validation for the description field. But js is not calling when i click the add button. Please help me how to call the js function.

**view file**

```
        = nested_form_for Task.new, :html=>{:multipart => true, :id => "vali" }, turboboost: true do |f|

         //form_fields

        = f.submit 'Add', class: 'btn-theme pull-right', :onsubmit => "validate()";
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vali").on("submit",validate({
        rules: {
        "task[description]": {required: true},
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: note: You have a trailing `,` that does not belong after the rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly call a function with parameters like that as you are executing it immediately and passing the result of the function to the submit event registration.

Add an anonymous function around your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vali").on("submit",function (){
        validate({
            rules: {
            "task[description]": {required: true},
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @TrueBlueAussie :) But i am trying in another way now it's working.